# When can we guarantee a closed form of statistical mechanical equations?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

Consider the equation of state:

$$P = \rho k_BT$$

where $P$ is pressure, $\rho$ is number density, $k_B$ is Boltzmann constant and $T$ is temperature. All variables are intensive thermodynamic variables.

I don't use $2$ moles of variables to describe the (position and momentum) "state" of $1$ mole of gas. I use 3 (in the ideal gas law), which I find remarkable and begs the question, when is this possible?

When can we guarantee a closed form of thermodynamic variables ([equation of state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_state)), for an arbitrary system like gas, plasma, solid, etc.?

I'm not sure when this can or cannot be done for a system.

Comment: IMO your question is **totally** unclear.

Comment: @JasonFunderberker Is the edit better?

Comment: What is a closed form of thermodynamic variables/ equation of state?

Comment: What does it mean *guarantee closed form of thermodynamic variables (equation of state) for an arbitrary system*? We usually can express pressure and the functions of state in terms of parameters of the system (as long as we have its Hamiltonian)... but not necessarily in a simple or even mathematically tractable equation.

Comment: @RogerVadim yes but I don't $2$ moles of variables to describe the (position and momentum) "state" of one mole of gas. I use 3 (in the ideal gas law) which I find remarkable and begs the question when is this possible?

Comment: It is about how many parameters you need to describe a distribution (see [Sufficient statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic)). The trick in stat mech is that we treat positions and momenta as random variables, distribution of which is parametrized by very few parameters, because the particles are identical. We need parameters that determine the configuration of the system (pressure, magnetic field, etc.) + temperature. Perhaps, you could try to reformulate your question more clearly... but now, that I understand you, I think it is an interesting one. +1

Comment: Yes and it's not obvious that all of the parameters are even extractable from stat mech to me. (and thanks)

Comment: But that's the whole point of thermodynamics: To make macroscopic predictions and to *not* deal with every degree of freedom. So your question could be rephrased as: What is the range of validity and applicability of thermodynamics?!

Comment: @Jason yes I do not deny the importance of thermodynamics. I don't  think there exists an equation of state of say a complex multicellular organism. Which means there are times I can and can't find a closed form on a physical system and I'm asking when

Comment: I think your question boils down to, "when can I write the equation of state for a system in closed form?" To which I suspect the correct answer is "only in very special ideal systems." In practice, I think what is done is to make more or less educated guesses about "reasonable" equations of state and fit them to empirical data. There's not a unique way to do this, and different methods/guesses/approximations will have different advantages and disadvantages, so that's why you can find many equations of state in the literature for nuclear matter, for example.

Answer (score 1):

First, note that there is a fundamental difference between knowing the 2 moles of variables describing a one-dimensional classical system of 1 mole of particles and the three variables appearing in your equation of state. Whereas the *microscopic description* fully characterizes the system in all its complexity, the equation of state is related to a statistical description of the system. This is, you could "read" the macroscopic information from the 2 moles microscopic variables, whereas the inverse is not true.

The statistical description of a system with many components does not rely (as far as I know) on any condition. However, the use of the theory of equilibrium statistical mechanics (Maxwell-Boltzmann-Gibbs) to make such a statistical description of equilibrium steady states does rely on some requirements.

- **The thermodynamic limit** ($N\rightarrow\infty$) is needed in order to ensure the equivalence between ensembles and the irrelevance of fluctuations.
- **The stability of the potential** (potential energy lower bound) is needed in order to avoid ["catastrophic configurations with infinite particles located in a finite space."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-stable_potential)
- **Short range interactions** ([interparticle potentials decay with exponents greater than the dimensionality
  of the embedding space](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370157313003761?casa_token=46L7I9yLwGgAAAAA:7d-NC7YIRmgRDIBn74SnHh_MWtai_uKAGcwBb9VPYU7St37rHMFhG23GKBWMVUems1RAN8OApg)) in order to ensure extensiveness of the thermodynamic potentials.

Apart from these general requirements, there is a non-trivial equation relating the pressure with the rest of the thermodynamic variables only when the partition function (supposing we are working in the canonical framework) depends explicitly on the volume.